# nf_register_hook not found in linux kernel 4.13-rc2 and later

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, netfilter

I just started learning about netfilter and I was trying to make a simple netfilter module, all the tutorials and HOW TOs register a hook function with `nf_register_hook()`, but I could not find one in linux kernels above 4.13-rc1.

As far as I understand, the `nf_register_hook()` function used to call the `_nf_register_hook()` function which further called `nf_register_net_hook()` function, iterating over each member of the `net` linked list, but then it gets a bit difficult for me to understand.

With, the `nf_register_hook()` function gone, I am in a fix as to how to register a hook.

The `nf_register_net_hook()` function is still there but, I am not really sure how that works.

So my question boils down to,

**How to register a netfilter hook in kernels above 4.13-rc1?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4,13,0)
    nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, reg)
#else
    nf_register_hook(reg)
#endif
```

Reference: [init_net](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.16/source/net/core/net_namespace.c#L37)

Comment: This works great!! I have one doubt though.... Why is `init_net` structure used ? Is it for holding all the netfilter hooks ?

Comment: Thanks for this @Wayne , this worked perfectly. And the link https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.16/source/net/core/net_namespace.c#L37 Was brilliant. Extremely good answer. Thumbs up.